# How to mock a list that will have certain values

Tags: java, easymock

I have a method:

```
expect(processor.process(arg1, list));
expectLastCall().anyTImes();
```

Now, I need the list to contain certain values. And the problem is that the values have to be added to the list in a right order, otherwise the list won't equal the real list. So I cannot just make a new list and add values into it, because if method `process` changed order of adding values into the list, the test would fail.
I tried this

```
List list=createMock(List.class);
expect(list.add(value1)).andReturn(true);
expect(lst.add(value2)).andReturn(true);
```

but he gives this exception:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Unexpected method call process(arg, [Listvalue1,Listvalue2]):
    process(arg, EasyMock for interface java.util.List): expected: 1, actual: 0
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `IAnswer` and `EasyMock.getCurrentArguments()` and then manually assert the contents of the list

```
expect(processor.process(arg1, list));
expectLastCall().anyTimes().andAnswer(new IAnswer<Object>() {
    public Object answer() throws Throwable {
        List myList = (List) EasyMock.getCurrentArguments()[1];
        // do your assertions on the list here (or change the order as required)
    }    
});
```

A big drawback of using EasyMock.getCurrentArguments() is that it is not "refactor-safe" (If you change the order of the parameters it will break the test).

Hope it helps.